# In foreign key column, should I use null or 0 to mean "no value"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Say I have a table of `items`, and one of the columns is `color_id`, a foreign key to a `colors` table. Not all items have colors. If make the column nullable, then when I refer to colors in a `where` clause I might need to use

```
where color_id is not distinct from ?
```

instead of the simpler

```
where color_id = ?
```

... in cases where that `?` might be null to search for items with no color.  Is this a bad idea? I don't mind the verbosity, but I was reading somewhere that **indexes don't work** for `is not distinct from`, and my first experiments confirm this.  A query with `is not distinct from` is taking much longer than a query with `=`.

Is it better to create a row in `colors` that represents "no color", maybe with `id = 0` and then make `items.color_id` a `not null` column?

Comment: I think the documentation and semantic correctness are worth a bit of extra key presses, but this is kinda opinion based.

Comment: Agreed. I updated question to clarify that I'm more concerned about it not using indexes on `is not distinct` vs `=`.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Postgres isn't able to use an index for it. You can check via `EXPLAIN` (though there may be other reasons why it won't choose to use an index).

Comment: I've tried multiple queries with explain, and it's doing sequential scans. I'm surprised too!

Comment: Propably using parital index on IS NULL condition on it will help.